# giving width and margin auto, but keeping backgrounds + Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere but I can't seem to find it.

I want the text inside the 2 flexboxed divs to also be inside the 90vw width, but I also want the backgrounds not to be shortened.

Anyways, here is what I have right now.

```css
.width {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.top {
  background-color: red;
}

.left {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <p class="width">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vestibulum magna mauris. Curabitur ultrices velit velit, non pulvinar dolor vulputate non. Duis tempus sodales eleifend. In eleifend posuere justo, id dignissim lacus sollicitudin ac. Cras cursus turpis at dignissim dignissim. Ut molestie lectus id dui rutrum, sed faucibus quam hendrerit. Nulla facilisi. In vitae massa nec purus dapibus dictum.</p>
 </div>

<div class="container width">
  <div class="left">
    <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vestibulum magna mauris. Curabitur ultrices velit velit, non pulvinar dolor vulputate non. Duis tempus sodales eleifend. In eleifend posuere justo, id dignissim lacus sollicitudin ac. Cras cursus turpis at dignissim dignissim. Ut molestie lectus id dui rutrum, sed faucibus quam hendrerit. Nulla facilisi. In vitae massa nec purus dapibus dictum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vestibulum magna mauris. Curabitur ultrices velit velit, non pulvinar dolor vulputate non. Duis tempus sodales eleifend. In eleifend posuere justo, id dignissim lacus sollicitudin ac. Cras cursus turpis at dignissim dignissim. Ut molestie lectus id dui rutrum, sed faucibus quam hendrerit. Nulla facilisi. In vitae massa nec purus dapibus dictum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier than you think:

- add `padding: 0 5vw` to space either side of `.top`
- `padding-left: 5vw` to `.left`
- `padding-right: 5vw` to `.right`
- and a `max-width: 100%` to `.top` to keep child elements inside

See the code below.

**Make sure to scroll further** and examine the extra demo code showing a basic responsive banding pattern without @media queries you can use right out of the box!

```css
/*
.width { REMOVE
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
}
*/
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%; /*ADD flexbox likes this */
}

.top {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0 5vw; /*ADD left and right */
}

p { margin: 0 } /* otherwise some HTMNL default margins */

.left {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding-left: 5vw; /*ADD align with top */
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
  padding-right: 5vw; /*ADD align with top */
}

*   { outline: 1px dashed } /* show element outlines for debug, remove when done */
```

```html
<div class="top pad">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vestibulum magna mauris. Curabitur ultrices velit velit, non pulvinar dolor vulputate non. Duis tempus sodales eleifend. In eleifend posuere justo, id dignissim lacus sollicitudin ac. Cras cursus turpis at dignissim dignissim. Ut molestie lectus id dui rutrum, sed faucibus quam hendrerit. Nulla facilisi. In vitae massa nec purus dapibus dictum.</p>
 </div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vestibulum magna mauris. Curabitur ultrices velit velit, non pulvinar dolor vulputate non. Duis tempus sodales eleifend. In eleifend posuere justo, id dignissim lacus sollicitudin ac. Cras cursus turpis at dignissim dignissim. Ut molestie lectus id dui rutrum, sed faucibus quam hendrerit. Nulla facilisi. In vitae massa nec purus dapibus dictum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vestibulum magna mauris. Curabitur ultrices velit velit, non pulvinar dolor vulputate non. Duis tempus sodales eleifend. In eleifend posuere justo, id dignissim lacus sollicitudin ac. Cras cursus turpis at dignissim dignissim. Ut molestie lectus id dui rutrum, sed faucibus quam hendrerit. Nulla facilisi. In vitae massa nec purus dapibus dictum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**DEMO ADD: generic responsive banding without @media queries**

Currently you can see a lot of (color)banded sites, with a hero, navigation, attractor, intro, gallery, demo, etc. bands with left and right a lot of white space (over 320px on either side on 1920px width displays).

Below a nice little responsive demo (based on your question) you can use right out of the box.

It has

- outer `.band` class acting as a main band container
- a `.band-inner` class holding **your** required content
- several responsive T/L/B/R paddings to generically space the content inside the inner band.
- without requiring any @media queries

Check the code for extended comments and go to [MathIsFun: Equation of a Straight Line](https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html) to get an easy, yet eleborate explanation on the math used.

```css
/* responsive root font-size: y=mx+b => p1(320,14) p2(1280,20) (see below equations) */
html { font-size: calc(.00625 * 100vmin + .75rem) }
/* 
    using "Intercept-slope" equation: y = mx + b for points p1(x1,y1), p2(x2,y2)
    where           m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
                    b = y1 - m * x1
                    x = 100VMIN/VH/VW (use vmin for fonts, vh for heights, vw for widths) 
*/
.band { /* main flexbox container for banded page layout */
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap; /* a row of several columns */

}
.band-inner { /* immediate child element, flexbox containers too */
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap; /* some default preferences */
    flex: 1 1 20rem;        /* grow to max available space, but wrap when less than 320px (mobile) */
}
.band-inner > * {    /* for mobile support: all inner child elements fill available space, also wrap at 320px */
    flex: 1 1 20rem; /* grow to max available space, but wrap when less than 320px (mobile) */
}
.pad { /* responsive band padding */
    padding: calc(0.025 * 100vh + 0.5rem)  /* responsive T/B p1(320,16), p2(1280,40)  */ 
             calc(0.19  * 100vw - 2.75rem) /* responsive L/R p1(320,16), p2(1920,320) */
}
.pad-t { padding-top   : calc(0.025 * 100vh + 0.5rem)  } 
.pad-b { padding-bottom: calc(0.025 * 100vh + 0.5rem)  } 
.pad-l { padding-left  : calc(0.19  * 100vw - 2.75rem) }
.pad-r { padding-right : calc(0.19  * 100vw - 2.75rem) }

body, p { margin: 0 } /* otherwise some HTMNL default margins, I always use this */

/* demo */
.band-inner p { padding: 1rem } /* nicely spaced inside parent */

.b1  { background-color: cornflowerblue }
.b2a { background-color: tomato }
.b2b { background-color: yellowgreen }

*   { outline: 1px dashed } /* show element outlines for debug, remove when done */
```

```html
<div class="band">
    <div class="band-inner pad">
        <p class="b1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vestibulum magna mauris. Curabitur ultrices velit velit, non pulvinar dolor vulputate non. Duis tempus sodales eleifend. In eleifend posuere justo, id dignissim lacus sollicitudin ac. Cras cursus turpis at dignissim dignissim. Ut molestie lectus id dui rutrum, sed faucibus quam hendrerit. Nulla facilisi. In vitae massa nec purus dapibus dictum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="band">
    <div class="band-inner pad">
        <p class="b2a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vestibulum magna mauris. Curabitur ultrices velit velit, non pulvinar dolor vulputate non. Duis tempus sodales eleifend. In eleifend posuere justo, id dignissim lacus sollicitudin ac. Cras cursus turpis at dignissim dignissim. Ut molestie lectus id dui rutrum, sed faucibus quam hendrerit. Nulla facilisi. In vitae massa nec purus dapibus dictum.</p>
        <p class="b2b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vestibulum magna mauris. Curabitur ultrices velit velit, non pulvinar dolor vulputate non. Duis tempus sodales eleifend. In eleifend posuere justo, id dignissim lacus sollicitudin ac. Cras cursus turpis at dignissim dignissim. Ut molestie lectus id dui rutrum, sed faucibus quam hendrerit. Nulla facilisi. In vitae massa nec purus dapibus dictum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea this works thanks, mind if I ask another question?

Comment: Is this a "good" way to make a whole website? I've always learned to begin with setting a width, never really thought about using paddings on the whole site.

Comment: Well, with millions of web developers, you will get just as many answer on what is 'good practice'. I tend to always take the shortest way from a to b. And I see this padding trick all the time. I was actually prepping a more generic flow for you to get you started. Will be ready in 15m or so...

Comment: This is the purpose of padding, block element should not require a width when they have to span the whole width,

Comment: @RenevanderLende wow thanks a lot for even putting time in making this. The comments are very helpful!

Comment: No worries, mate, I just copied the code straight from my own code and constructed this nifty demo. https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html has a easy to understand explanation of the math used... (I will now adjust my post a bit to point to the extra demo)

Answer (score 0):

I moved your class `width` and put it along your `top` and instead I added padding to the left and right side of the `p`.

Originally, from the code you posted in your question, the red upper container was not following your `90vw` that you wanted so I had to change it.

```css
.width {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.width_half {
  width: 45vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.top {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.left {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.right {
  background-color: silver;
}
.left p,
.right p {
  padding: 0 3vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <p class="width">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vestibulum magna mauris. Curabitur ultrices velit velit, non pulvinar dolor vulputate non. Duis tempus sodales eleifend. In eleifend posuere justo, id dignissim lacus sollicitudin ac. Cras cursus turpis at dignissim dignissim. Ut molestie lectus id dui rutrum, sed faucibus quam hendrerit. Nulla facilisi. In vitae massa nec purus dapibus dictum.</p>
 </div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vestibulum magna mauris. Curabitur ultrices velit velit, non pulvinar dolor vulputate non. Duis tempus sodales eleifend. In eleifend posuere justo, id dignissim lacus sollicitudin ac. Cras cursus turpis at dignissim dignissim. Ut molestie lectus id dui rutrum, sed faucibus quam hendrerit. Nulla facilisi. In vitae massa nec purus dapibus dictum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vestibulum magna mauris. Curabitur ultrices velit velit, non pulvinar dolor vulputate non. Duis tempus sodales eleifend. In eleifend posuere justo, id dignissim lacus sollicitudin ac. Cras cursus turpis at dignissim dignissim. Ut molestie lectus id dui rutrum, sed faucibus quam hendrerit. Nulla facilisi. In vitae massa nec purus dapibus dictum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there no way to keep the "full size wide" backgrounds and keep the text inside the 90vw?

Comment: Oh, I mis-interpreted what you wanted. Give me a sec to edit it for you.

Comment: and yes the red was not following the 90vw because I wanted it to be the full width so I used .width on the text, and now I want the full width on both bottom divs while the text is also within that 90vw

Comment: @HoyHymHo How's this? This is the best I could do.

Comment: Just adding padding compensate right? unfortunately if the screen gets larger the text won't line up. you can already see it if you expand the snippetthanks for trying though